# Remote Desktop Viewer can't connect to "found" computers

Tags: remote-desktop, avahi, upnp, dlna, vinagre

I use **Remote Desktop Viewer** to connect from my Laptop (Ubuntu 11.04) to my PC (Ubuntu 10.04).  But I can only connect if I type the PC's address directly.

If I use the ***Find*** option (UPnP?), to search for visible computers on the network, it finds the PC.  Yet when I select it, the Remote Desktop Viewer immediatly turns off.  No error messages.

Since the PC has no static IP, I have to check every time what the current IP address is, so having it found by the RDV would be great.

BTW, I am using the default RD apps that Ubuntu brings.

### Update

I just started it through a terminal and the result was `Segmentation Fault`.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)